# TexStudio keeps overwriting the ini file

Tags: texstudio, bugs

I just tried to switch from Texmaker to TexStudio, and I would prefer to stay there. I experienced a bug with the Circumflex key, effectively making TexStudio unusable for me, but I could fix it by adding the line `Editor%20Key%20Mapping\0=20483` to the .ini file.

The problem stopped occuring for a few minutes, then suddenly reappeared. I checked the .ini file and the line I had added was no longer there. I have repeated the process several times, and it keeps disappearing every few minutes.

I would greatly appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please choose another user name ;-)

Comment: Have you closed the program, edited the ini and reopened?  That's what you should do.

Comment: Any updates here? Did ChrisH's comments help?